# How to handle multiple shipping origins and their tax calculations in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Im facing an issue related to magento-1.9. Let me talk a bit about the context, we are part of a franchising business and each franchise works like an independent business.

In magento we can create a website -> store -> store-view per each franchise and manage them individually but found a problem related to taxes and shipping.

Magento only allows for one shipping origin but in our case we have one shipping origin per franchise/website since each franchise will ship its goods like an independent business.

What plugin/service/workflow would you recommend to handle multiple shipping origins keeping in mind that we have to calculate taxes based on this multiple shipping origins? (this are USA taxes).

Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tax can be set at the store view level, through System -> Configuration, under the sales section, select Tax. Here you can set the tax setting per store view, just make sure you change the configuration scope accordingly.

In regards to the shipping origin, unfortunately this is at a website level. Hence I suggest changing your setup to instead use a separate website for each franchise instead of a separate store view.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Paul.